# How to create .key file with specific text

Tags: vb.net, filewriter

I've been trying to make a program that is able to create a file with a .key extension, which contains a 5 line text.

It is fundamental to have 5 lines, otherwise it won't work.

I use

```
   Dim filepath As String = TextBox1.Text + "\\rarreg.key"
            Dim rarreg As New IO.StreamWriter(filepath, True)
            rarreg.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, hiddenTxt))
```

The hiddenTxt contains all the text needed and it's multilined.

However, when I click on the button to call this functions, it succesfully creates the file, but it comes empty.

Comment: Add following : rarreg.Flush()    rarreg.Close()  rarreg.Dispose()

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: RAR registration data
CrYs18 DL4all.com...

it adds this text, but how can i get rid of System.Windows.Forms.TextBox ?

It also doesn't show the full code.

Comment: Just a FYI: your `String.Join` is unnecessary. It's not appending anything since the overload used will be the ParamArray with only 1 string passed into it (`hiddenText`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
       ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim filepath As String = ""
        Dim dialog As New SaveFileDialog
        dialog.DefaultExt = "key"
        dialog.FileName = "rarreg.key"
        dialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\temp"
        Dim results As DialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog()
        If results <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            filepath = dialog.FileName
        End If​
```

Comment: Whats this have to do with a `savefiledialog`¿

Comment: Read users comments In original posting above.

Comment: What isn't working?  It been fully tested.  If it is not working, you placed it in the wrong location.

Comment: The code doesn't do the saving.  Just gets the filename.  I just got rid of the textbox.